# How should I declare the return type of a function that returns a $q promise with no data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have this function:

```
getMethod = (): ng.IPromise<any> => {
    if (1 == 2) {
        return this.$q.when();
    }
    var defer = this.$q.defer();
    this.$http({
        url: '/abc',
        method: "GET"
    })
        .success((): void => {
            //
            defer.resolve();
        })
        .error((): void => {
            //
            defer.reject();
        })
    return defer.promise;
}
```

This works okay and the promises returned do not contain any data.

So I changed the first line to:

```
getMethod = (): ng.IPromise<void> => {
```

Now I get an error:

> Error 3   Cannot convert 'ng.IPromise<{}>' to 'ng.IPromise':
>       Types of property 'then' of types 'ng.IPromise<{}>' and 'ng.IPromise' are incompatible:

Can someone give me advice on how I should correctly declare the return type. I know using  works but it does not seem a clean solution if the function really always returns void.

Comment: Please add the relevant tag for the language syntax.

Comment: So *Why* does your promise not resolve with a value? It usually should. Btw, [avoid the deferred antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-deferred-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)

Comment: There's more to this code but it is simplified for this question. The promise returns with a success or failure which is enough.

Comment: @Steve - That seesm not to be an option in the interface spec for ng.IPromise

Comment: @SamanthaJ Change the line `var defer = this.$q.defer();` to `var defer = this.$q.defer<void>();` (explicitly specify the void type argument)

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if I understand what you are trying to do , but this transpiles without errors

```
   getMethod = (): ng.IPromise<void> => {
        var defer:ng.IDeferred<void> = this.$q.defer<void>();
        this.$http({ url: '/abc', method: "GET"}).then(
            payload => defer.resolve(),
            error=> defer.reject()
        );
        return defer.promise;
    }
```

It could probably mean that you want to know the operation completed 
I'd've choose observer pattern, messaging ,a callback? 
it seems to me that promises are better to encapsulate values, maybe_value,